# Implicit conversion from JToken in Json.NET

Tags: c#, type-conversion, json.net

Using [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json), I see that all of the conversions of native types **to** `JToken` are implicit, but conversions **from** `JToken` are explicit.

My motivation is to avoid the explicit casts in `if` statements, method calls etc. For example, it would have been nice if the last `if` did not throw:

```
string dummyJson = @"{'ShouldDoStuff': true}";
dynamic parsed = JValue.Parse(dummyJson);

// Works:
bool explicitShouldDoStuff = parsed.ShouldDoStuff; 

// Also works:
if ((bool)parsed.ShouldDoStuff)
    Console.WriteLine("Hooray, there's a rosebush?");

// Throws RuntimeBinderException: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue' to 'bool'
if (parsed.ShouldDoStuff)   
    Console.WriteLine("Die you gravy-sucking pigs");
```

Is there a way to make conversions from `JToken` to native types implicit as well?

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: @meilke - rephrased the question

Comment: Perhaps you should consider deserializing into strongly typed classes instead of using `dynamic`.

Comment: You always have the option to create a dynamic wrapper for `JToken` that will return properties using the most appropriate type. But it might be more trouble than it's worth. It's unfortunate that the dynamic implementation isn't as robust is it probably could.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for explicit operators is that implicit operators cause all sorts of problems. So, no, you can't do it, it's by design.

However, in addition to explicit cast, you can also get `Value` property:

```
if (parsed.ShouldDoStuff.Value)
    Console.WriteLine("Die you gravy-sucking pigs");
```

I think it's cleaner than type cast.

Comment: can you give an example for problems resulting from using implicit cast operators?

Comment: A few articles: http://netvignettes.wordpress.com/2011/04/24/implicit-conversion-operators-are-bad/ , http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/05/24/605974.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind getting your hands dirty working with dynamic meta objects, you could write a wrapper class that can convert the value to a `bool` behind the scenes.

First of all the implementation of the wrapper:

```
public class JTokenWrapper : DynamicObject
{
    public JTokenWrapper(JToken token)
    {
        if (token == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("token");
        this.Token = token;
    }
    public JToken Token { get; private set; }

    public override DynamicMetaObject GetMetaObject(Expression parameter)
    {
        return new JValueUnwrapperMetaObject(parameter, Token);
    }

    class JValueUnwrapperMetaObject : ProjectedDynamicMetaObjectWrapper<JToken>
    {
        public JValueUnwrapperMetaObject(Expression expression, JToken token)
            : base(expression, ExpressionSelector, token)
        {
        }

        private static Expression ExpressionSelector(Expression expression)
        {
            return LinqExpression.Property(
                LinqExpression.Convert(expression, typeof(JTokenWrapper)),
                "Token"
            );
        }

        public override DynamicMetaObject BindGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder)
        {
            return UnwrappedValue(base.BindGetMember(binder));
        }

        public override DynamicMetaObject BindGetIndex(GetIndexBinder binder, DynamicMetaObject[] indexes)
        {
            return UnwrappedValue(base.BindGetIndex(binder, indexes));
        }

        private DynamicMetaObject UnwrappedValue(DynamicMetaObject getter)
        {
            var expr = GenerateUnwrapperExpression(getter.Expression);
            return new DynamicMetaObject(expr, getter.Restrictions, getter.Value);
        }

        private static readonly Dictionary<JTokenType, Func<Expression, Expression>> UnwrappedTypes = new Dictionary<JTokenType, Func<Expression, Expression>>
        {
            { JTokenType.Boolean,   UnwrapBoolean   },
            { JTokenType.String,    UnwrapString    },
            { JTokenType.Integer,   UnwrapInteger   },
        };

        private static Expression ExplicitConvert(Expression token, Type type)
        {
            return LinqExpression.Convert(
                token,
                type,
                typeof(JToken).GetMethods().Where(m => m.Name == "op_Explicit").Single(m => m.ReturnType == type)
            );
        }

        private static Expression UnwrapBoolean(Expression token)
        {
            return ExplicitConvert(token, typeof(bool));
        }

        private static Expression UnwrapString(Expression token)
        {
            return ExplicitConvert(token, typeof(string));
        }

        private static Expression UnwrapInteger(Expression token)
        {
            // TODO: figure out the appropriate type
            return token;
        }

        private Expression GenerateUnwrapperExpression(Expression value)
        {
            var token = LinqExpression.Variable(typeof(JToken));
            var returnTarget = LinqExpression.Label(typeof(object));
            return LinqExpression.Block(
                typeof(object),
                new ParameterExpression[] { token },
                LinqExpression.Assign(token, LinqExpression.Convert(value, typeof(JToken))),
                LinqExpression.Switch(
                    LinqExpression.Property(token, "Type"),
                    UnwrappedTypes.Select(x =>
                        LinqExpression.SwitchCase(
                            LinqExpression.Return(returnTarget,
                                LinqExpression.Convert(
                                    x.Value(token),
                                    typeof(object)
                                )
                            ),
                            LinqExpression.Constant(x.Key)
                        )
                    ).ToArray()
                ),
                LinqExpression.Label(
                    returnTarget,
                    LinqExpression.New(
                        typeof(JTokenWrapper).GetConstructors().Single(),
                        LinqExpression.Convert(value, typeof(JToken))
                    )
                )
            );
        }
    }
}
```

And the support classes needed:

```
public abstract class DynamicMetaObjectWrapper : DynamicMetaObject
{
    public DynamicMetaObjectWrapper(Expression expression, DynamicMetaObject wrappedMetaObject)
        : base(expression, wrappedMetaObject.Restrictions, wrappedMetaObject.Value)
    {
        this.MetaObject = wrappedMetaObject;
    }
    public DynamicMetaObjectWrapper(DynamicMetaObject wrappedMetaObject)
        : this(wrappedMetaObject.Expression, wrappedMetaObject)
    {
    }
    public DynamicMetaObject MetaObject { get; private set; }

    public override DynamicMetaObject BindBinaryOperation(BinaryOperationBinder binder, DynamicMetaObject arg)
    {
        return MetaObject.BindBinaryOperation(binder, arg);
    }

    public override DynamicMetaObject BindConvert(ConvertBinder binder)
    {
        return MetaObject.BindConvert(binder);
    }
    public override DynamicMetaObject BindCreateInstance(CreateInstanceBinder binder, DynamicMetaObject[] args)
    {
        return MetaObject.BindCreateInstance(binder, args);
    }

    public override DynamicMetaObject BindDeleteIndex(DeleteIndexBinder binder, DynamicMetaObject[] indexes)
    {
        return MetaObject.BindDeleteIndex(binder, indexes);
    }

    public override DynamicMetaObject BindDeleteMember(DeleteMemberBinder binder)
    {
        return MetaObject.BindDeleteMember(binder);
    }

    public override DynamicMetaObject BindGetIndex(GetIndexBinder binder, DynamicMetaObject[] indexes)
    {
        return MetaObject.BindGetIndex(binder, indexes);
    }

    public override DynamicMetaObject BindGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder)
    {
        return MetaObject.BindGetMember(binder);
    }

    public override DynamicMetaObject BindInvoke(InvokeBinder binder, DynamicMetaObject[] args)
    {
        return MetaObject.BindInvoke(binder, args);
    }

    public override DynamicMetaObject BindInvokeMember(InvokeMemberBinder binder, DynamicMetaObject[] args)
    {
        return MetaObject.BindInvokeMember(binder, args);
    }

    public override DynamicMetaObject BindSetIndex(SetIndexBinder binder, DynamicMetaObject[] indexes, DynamicMetaObject value)
    {
        return MetaObject.BindSetIndex(binder, indexes, value);
    }

    public override DynamicMetaObject BindSetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, DynamicMetaObject value)
    {
        return MetaObject.BindSetMember(binder, value);
    }

    public override DynamicMetaObject BindUnaryOperation(UnaryOperationBinder binder)
    {
        return MetaObject.BindUnaryOperation(binder);
    }

    public override IEnumerable<string> GetDynamicMemberNames()
    {
        return MetaObject.GetDynamicMemberNames();
    }
}
public abstract class ProjectedDynamicMetaObjectWrapper<TProvider> : DynamicMetaObjectWrapper where TProvider : class, IDynamicMetaObjectProvider
{
    public ProjectedDynamicMetaObjectWrapper(Expression expression, Func<Expression, Expression> expressionSelector, TProvider provider)
        : base(expression, provider.GetMetaObject(expressionSelector(expression)))
    {
    }
}
```

Then all you have to do is wrap the token with this wrapper:

```
var jsonStr = @"{""ShouldDoStuff"":true}";
var value = JValue.Parse(jsonStr);
dynamic wrapped = new JTokenWrapper(value);

if (wrapped.ShouldDoStuff)
{
    // success!
}
```